# Log in button not working with Facebook sdk

Tags: android, facebook, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I'm using react-native-fbsdk for Facebook SDK, and when I click on login button pop up shows up and disappears very fast. It is working on iOS and Android simulator, but it is not working on android .apk build for the device. It is a release build. I've followed everything from official getting started page. Any help appreciated. Thank you.

---

**Update**

I solved the problem by signing out from my Facebook application, and after that I was using a Facebook test account in this purposes.

Comment: can you place a log or something so that we find the issue? 

apk hash key are diff then debug one in android, while ios dont care about release or debug

Comment: @Jigar Yes, I was checking that also, and I've added new hash keys to facebook developer console. No error is thrown, just a pop up with facebook logo that disappears.

Comment: place console in login method or use try catch to find the error that fb through

Comment: @Jigar Oh, I've tried that also, but I can't console.log cause it is working on simulator. And on device I don't have any error, just a pop up with facebook logo on it that disappears very fast.

Comment: so login flow is working after the fb click ?

Comment: @Jigar On iOS it is working and I can proceed with flow, but on android device when I click on login button, I see loader animation showing up and one small pop up with an icon for Facebook on it, and after one second or maybe less it disappears. Could it be related to hash keys? I have a keystore for release build.

Comment: umm there is less visibility on this issue to say anything :(

Comment: Can you put your code here?

Comment: i am getting same issue !